# how create mpeg-ts stream over http with existing hls (stream )

Tags: apache, ffmpeg, video-streaming, mpeg, http-live-streaming

currently i`m using ffmpeg to create hls live stream and the same was delivered by apache server.
sample HLS stream url,"http://localhost/cam/live1.m3u8"

willing add mpegts stream option.. I don`t want to run one more service for mpeg-ts creation like ffserver or vlc.. Anyone guide me to achieve this goal.

expected transport stream url  "http://localhost/cam/live1.ts"

Comment: I am not completely sure what you are asking but if you need to play HLS in the browser then you can use a javascript HLS player like: [hls.js](https://github.com/dailymotion/hls.js/) (open source), [viblast](https://viblast.com/player) (commercial).

Comment: you can output from ffmpeg to multiple outputs: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs

Comment: i have found similar feature in "xtream-codes" iptv panel, but its paid version, i`m looking for open source.